# A dialog with ShowInTaskbar=false shown from another dialog is hidden from Alt+Tab

Tags: .net, winforms

Hopefully you aren't totally confused by the title, as it's difficult to concisely explain. Before I explain, though, I want to clarify I know that ShowInTaskbar=false plus FormBorderStyle=FixedToolWindow will result in my application not appearing in Alt+Tab, but that's not my issue.

I have a main form that spawns another form (call it Form B) using ShowDialog(). At this point everything is fine - Alt+Tab works as I'd expect. However, in some situations I spawn yet another form from Form B using ShowDialog() (call this new form Form C). I would like Form C to not appear in the taskbar, so I set for Form C ShowInTaskbar=false. I don't bother changing the FormBorderStyle of Form C.

What happens is my entire application is hidden from Alt+Tab while form C is visible, which is not what I want. I simply want form C to not be on the taskbar, but I need alt+tab to either the main form or form B. What's weird is if I don't show form C and change form B to ShowInTaskbar=false then Alt+Tab behaves how I want (despite form B not being in the taskbar Alt+Tab lets me switch to my application).

It seems showing a dialog that's hidden from the taskbar *from another dialog* breaks alt+tab behavior. Has anyone else experienced this? Is there a workaround available?

Comment: I discovered something interesting - if form B is also ShowInTaskbar=false then everything works as I want. This is an acceptable workaround for me, but I'm still curious why it seems to be broken in my original attempt.

Comment: It is *very* unusual to have a dialog also have a taskbar button.  It serves no obvious purpose, you can always get back to it by clicking the main window's button.  Windows needs to make some judgement calls to guess what kind of toplevel window should appear in the Alt+Tab strip.  Clearly you are breaking its guesses.